# Show Text in TextView when video reaches current time Android

Tags: android, android-videoview

I want to make a text appear in TextView when the video reaches current time. I've tried this code :

```
public class VideoActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String MY_AD_UNIT_ID = null;
    protected static final String TAG = null;
    private AdView adView;
    int waktu;
    Button btncek;
    private MediaController controller = null;
    TextView textView2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.videoplayer);
    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    String urlbarus = getIntent().getStringExtra("urlbaru");
    final VideoView videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);

    videoView.setVideoPath(urlbarus);


    MediaController.MediaPlayerControl mcEvents = new MediaController.MediaPlayerControl() {        
        public void start() {
            videoView.start();
        }

        public void seekTo(int pos) {
            videoView.seekTo(pos);         
        }

        public void pause() {
            videoView.pause();
        }

        public boolean isPlaying() {            
            return videoView.isPlaying();
        }

        public int getDuration() {          
            return videoView.getDuration();
        }

        public int getCurrentPosition() {           
            return videoView.getCurrentPosition();
        }

        public boolean canSeekForward() {           
            return true;
        }

        public boolean canSeekBackward() {
            return true;
        }

        public boolean canPause() {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public int getBufferPercentage() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }
    };

    controller = new MediaController(this);
    controller.setMediaPlayer(mcEvents);
    controller.setAnchorView(findViewById(R.id.wrapper));

    videoView.start();


  if(mcEvents.getCurrentPosition()>=10000){
            textView2.setText("kebaca");
            }

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    //the MediaController will hide after 3 seconds - tap the screen to make it appear again
    controller.show();
    return false;
}
```

This is the code for showing text :

```
if(mcEvents.getCurrentPosition()>=10000){
    textView2.setText("kebaca");
}
```

I have tried that code, but nothing happens (textview2 does not show the text)

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like..

```
    final MediaController.MediaPlayerControl mcEvents = ....

    textView2.setText(""); // edited

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (mcEvents.getCurrentPosition()<10000){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ignored) { }
            }
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    textView2.setText("kebaca");
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();
```

Comment: That makes force close, Log cat says : Fatal Exception:Main, java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: owh, The problem was I forgot to declare findviewbyid for the textview, after I declare it, all is worked..

Comment: There was a problem again, that code is not really works, when I changed to mcEvents.getCurrentPosition()>10000 (I use if), the text has showed from the first when the activity launch (the appropriate action is after 10000 ms, the text is show)..